# Is proguard minifying my constants?

Tags: android, proguard, android-lifecycle

In a recent release of my App I added proguard. A weird error started to show up:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.siplay.myapp.b.e.e.b()' on a null object reference
```

The error is being triggered in this line:

```
public boolean isVideo() {
    return Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO.equals(mImage.getType());
}
```

`MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO` is a constant and is declared like this:

```
public class Media implements Parcelable {
    ...
    public static final String MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = "video";
    ...
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO, Media.MEDIA_TYPE_THUMB})
    public @interface MediaTypes {}
    ...
    public void setType(@MediaTypes String type) {
        ...
}
```

I read in many posts that Proguard doesn't mess with the constants declarations. However it must be the offuscated constant or the `mImage` object. The stacktrace tells me that this NPE is triggered right after I initialize the views:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mImage = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(Constants.BUNDLE_IMAGE);
            ...
        }

        mVideoLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (isVideo()) { //HERE
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(Constants.BUNDLE_IMAGE, mImage);
        ...
    }
}
```

Maybe this is happening because I hooked from onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> replace `com.example` with base package of `Media` Class and put this
>   line in proguard file

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }
```

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna try it. I'll let you know if it fixes it.

Comment: Everything OK so far